# how to decode a qr code and use the text in a php variable

Tags: php

I am processing an online form to which a qr code is being added for identification.  How do I decode that QR and use the decoded text as a variable in php.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpqrcode/